# How to print publisher attributes in subscription code mqtt?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspberry-pi3

I have my subscription code running on raspberry pi. Since it is connected to multiple publishers, I want to print out the publisher attributes like its name ID. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not.

The subscriber knows nothing about the publisher, only the topic the message was published on.

Comment: Can you guide me how to  print topic name? here is my code

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print  *topic* "Message received: "  + message.payload

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out earlier that a subscriber doesn't know anything about the publisher. However, topic can be print using this:

```
def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
  print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())+ " "+msg.topic+" " +str(msg.payload)
```